# import a rule to a Drupal 7 with Drush

Tags: drupal

How can I import a rule to a Drupal 7 site with Drush.

I export a rule from an existing Drupal 7 site and I want to import it to another site, but I don't want to do it from the UI.

I want to use Drush or some kind of script.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `drush` and a feature/custom deploy module. Please see this link for details: https://www.drupal.org/project/hook_update_deploy_tools#import-rule